# How to sort an NSArray of objects using another NSArray which contains the ordered keys of objects?

Tags: iphone, sorting, nsarray

for example, if I have an object:

```
@interface MyObject
{
    __id;
    __data;
}
```

and I have an NSArray of such object:

```
id=4
data=Apple
id=5
data=Banana
id=6
data=Orange
```

I also have an NSArray of ids:

```
{"5", "4", "6"}
```

now I want to sort the array of objects by ids to be in the order in the second array, so the result should be:

```
id=5
data=Banana
id=4
data=Apple
id=6
data=Orange
```

Is it possible(in ObjC for iPhone)? What is the most efficient way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `- (NSArray *)sortedArrayUsingComparator:(NSComparator)cmptr` function of the NSArray class.

You should write your own comparator block that will return ordering depending on the position of id in the ids array - ie return NSOrderedAscending when idA is further from the start of the array than idB.

Hope this helps.